# Swift dynamicCast error while inserting new object to database

Tags: ios, core-data, swift, nsmanagedobject, dynamic-cast

I have a dictionary which I have all data that I want to insert into database as new object. The problem is when I try to cast the newly created object it gives me exception in:

```
libswift_stdlib_core.dylib`swift_dynamicCast:
```

part of assembly code.
The code that i am using is like this:

```
    var group:Group  
    if (array.count == 0) {
        group = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Group", inManagedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext) as Group

    }
```

and the structure of Group class is like this:

```
    @objc(Group)
    class Group:NSManagedObject{

        @NSManaged var createDate:NSString
        @NSManaged var groupPictureUrl:NSString
        @NSManaged var groupTypeId:NSString
        @NSManaged var isDepartment:NSString
        @NSManaged var lastMessageRead:NSString
        @NSManaged var name:NSString
        @NSManaged var unreadMessageCount:NSString
        @NSManaged var groupId:NSString
        @NSManaged var lastSync:NSString
}
```

I have also a subclass of `NSManagedObject` named `AppData` which has the same structure with Group class. And at inserting part of my code if I replace Group with `AppData` it works and I can insert into `AppData` table. As I said before they have the same structure except parameters. But when I try to insert Group object it gives me dynamic cast exception. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you checked whether the object is created (i.e. there is a non nil pointer) before the cast?  Perhaps there is something strange with the 'group' keyword...

Comment: I read almost all answers that I could find on StackOverflow.  Some claimed that adding @objc(Group) would work but it didn't work for me.  Some claimed that adding the module name in front of Group (from entity inspector) would work.  That didn't work for me neither.  I even tried different variation of the two approaches.  But the solutions still didn't work for me when running unit test.  It's baffling that simply creating an entity would be so challenging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by initializing the entity object differently, if you implement the initiation method from super class(NSManagedObject) like: (in Group.swift)

```
    init(entity: NSEntityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext!) {
        super.init(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
    }
```

you can create the object like this:

```
    var desc:NSEntityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Group",inManagedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext)
    var group:Group = Group(entity:desc, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: appDelegate.managedObjectContext)
```

most of solutions i have read was making the initiation like this:

```
  var group:Group = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Group", inManagedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext) as Group
```

so this was the problem and object could not be casted to custom managed object class with this way. Thanks to everyone.

Comment: This solution works.  But I need to manually add the init() back to the files whenever I regenerate my models from xcode.  I wish apple would just fix the problem.