# CoreData won't let me down cast model object

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8

I don't know if this is by design or a serious bug in xcode/swift, but down casting model has been a big pain in the butt.  First I found `NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(_:inManagedObjectContext:)` would not let me down cast to my model unless I override `init(entity: NSEntityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext!)` as a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25200149/swift-dynamiccast-error-while-inserting-new-object-to-database).

I even tried adding the module name before my model (ie, MyApp.Employee) in the entity inspector.  As many as others have claimed working, it just didn't work for me somehow.

Now I also discovered that `objectWithId()` won't let me down cast neither.  Unit test would just failed with `CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named 'Employee' for entity 'Employee' Class not found, using fault NSManageObject instead`.

> let employeeFromDB =
>   managedObjectContext.objectWithID(employee.objectID) as
>   Employee

Again, adding the module name in front of the model class or `objc(Employee)` to the file didn't work.

The expected behavior is obviously different from obj-c and makes porting cumbersome.

Anyone has similar experience and solution?

Comment: Report a bug and see what Apple say. The quicker you report it, the more likely it'll be fixed in the next seed.

Comment: I had similar experience. It went away after adding the module name and re-generating the class file.

Comment: @MirekE When I added the module name, xcode would strangely generate a extra file named exactly like the module name and the presence of the file didn't make any sense.  Did you see an extra file generated?

Comment: Yes, same here. I just ignored the file and used my old one.

Answer (score 0):

So far the [best explanation](https://devforums.apple.com/message/983942) I could find is in the forum.